# OKD (OpenShift) 4.7 - add new baremetal master node to existing cluster

Tags: openshift, okd

I've deployed a OKD 4.7 cluster with 3 baremetal master nodes.

Now i would like to expand the cluster by adding a new master node, but i can't find anything on the documentation about it, could only find how to add new worker nodes.

Any one knows the procedure to add a new master node?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, only 3 master nodes are available on the OKD cluster at the moment.
Refer [Cluster Masters](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/control-plane.html#defining-masters_control-plane) as follows.

```
Exactly three master nodes must be used for all production deployments.
```